# Parametrization of truncated sphere not centered on the origin.

Tags: spherical-coordinates, parametrization

The sphere is $x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=25$ with $0 \le z$ and i wanted to parametrize it with spherical coordinates.

How does it change with the fact that it is not centered on the origin? 
From what value to what value are the variables defined? And what whould happen if the sphere is $x^2+y^2+(z-5)^2=25$?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The answer depends on what exactly is the question. Do you have to use the **standard** spherical coordinates $x=\rho\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)$, $y=\rho\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)$, $z=\rho\cos(\phi)$? Or is the question to find any parametrization, in which case we can use "modified spherical" coordinates? Both questions have answers, but these are two different questions.

Comment: I guess it is with the standard spherical coordinates, never hear of the modified ones. Could you explain me what is the difference?

Comment: "standard spherical coordinates" refers to the parametrization I used in my answer. There are other ways to parametrize a sphere, but they are nearly guaranteed to be uglier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parametrization, as I assume you're referring to, is the description of the points on a surface in three dimensions as:

$$x = f(s, t)\\y=g(s, t)\\z = h(s, y).$$

If this is the case, to translate a curve like a sphere centered at the origin, all you have to do is add the "new center's" coordinates to the parametrization centered at the origin.

For example, the parametrization of a sphere with radius $\rho$ centered at the origin is:

$$x=\rho\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)\\
y = \rho\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)\\
z = \rho\cos(\phi)$$

While the same sphere centered at $\langle2, \pi, e\rangle$ would be parametrized:

$$x=2+\rho\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)\\
y = \pi+\rho\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)\\
z = e+\rho\cos(\phi)$$

In these cases, your bounds on $\theta$ and $\phi$ don't change.

---

For such a limit as $0\le z$, you would have to change the bounds of $\phi$ and $\theta$. Simply take the bounds used previously, which in the parametrization I gave were $0<\phi\le\pi$ and $0 < \theta \le 2\pi$, and take their intersection with the bounds of $\phi$ and $\theta$ for which the restriction holds.

For your example given, we have the parametrization:

$$x=5\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)\\
y = 5\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)\\
z = 1+5\cos(\phi)\\
0<\phi\le\pi\\
0<\theta\le2\pi$$

So asserting that $0 \le z$ implies $0\le 1+5\cos(\phi)$, which in turn implies that $-\frac15\le\cos(\phi)$. The intersection of this and the previous bound on $\phi$ gives that the bound is $0 < \phi \le \arccos(-\frac15).$

The bounds on $\theta$ are unchanged by restrictions on $z$ in this specific case.

Does this help?

Comment: Make sense, Thanks! There is any change in the range of values of $\phi$ and $\theta$?

Comment: Nope! If you want an intuitive idea of how parametrizations work, I would advise you to go mess around with some 2d ones on desmos or whatever you favorite graphing calculator is.

Comment: If the sphere has radius $1$, then its parametrization (in the middle of your answer) wouldn't have any $\rho$'s in it because $\rho=1$ for all points on the sphere. Similarly for the other one.

Comment: @zipirovich Sorry, that was me being lazy about the equations. It has been fixed.

Comment: Also, the bounds **would** have to change based on the restrictions like $0\le z$. You would still end up with a semisphere if you kept the same bounds, but not the same restriction of $0\le z$.